# PDFKit: send the generated pdf to browser but don't save it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

Is it possible to generate a pdf with PDFKit and send it to the browser without save the file to filesystem?
I'm using PDFKit 0.8.2 and Rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PDFKit documentation there is a way to get an inline pdf like so:

```rb
kit = PDFKit.new(html, page_size: 'A4')
pdf = kit.to_pdf
```

You can send this `pdf` to the browser with `send_data` in your Controller.

```rb
send_data(pdf,
          filename: 'some_fancy_file_name.pdf',
          disposition: 'attachment',
          type: :pdf)
```

Put this together in an action in your Controller and there you go. (Don’t forget to add an appropriate route!)

```rb
def download_pdf
  html = # render as needed
  kit = PDFKit.new(html, page_size: 'A4')
  pdf = kit.to_pdf

  send_data(pdf,
            filename: 'some_fancy_file_name.pdf',
            disposition: 'attachment',
            type: :pdf)
end
```